# Payload parsing error (Soap 1.1 vs Soap 1.2)

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a problem with a payload on WSO2 ESB.

My endpoint is answering correctly when I send a SOAP 1.1 message.

I made a proxy that takes parameters and convert it to SOAP. Then send it through my Endpoint.

The problem is that my message is correctly formed (I think so) but I always have this error:

> ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream
>   org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException:
>   ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1] Message: Content is not allowed in
>   prolog.

It seems to probably be a content type error of some sort if I check this on Slashdot: [WSO2 ESB Content is not allowed in prolog exception in a OutSecuence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053289/wso2-esb-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-exception-in-a-outsecuence) but even when I defined format="soap11" in my endpoint, it seems that the envelope is SOAP 1.2

My proxy definition is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Test11"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
                <ns2:QueryReqWS xmlns:ns2="http://hiddenUrl.com/">
                <TOTO xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" 
                    ITSVersion="XML_1.0" 
                    xmlns:mif="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif" 
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 urn:hl7-org:v3 file:/schemas/TOTO.xsd">

                    <id root="1234"/>
                     ...
                    <controlActEvent classCode="CACT" moodCode="EVN">
                       ...
                        <queryByParameter>
                            <queryId root="456"/>
                            <responseModalityCode code="R"/>
                            <parameterList>
                                <Gender>
                                    <value code="$1" >
                                    </value>
                                </Gender>  
                                <BirthDate>
                                    <value xsi:type="TS" specializationType="TS.FULLDATE" value="$2"/>
                                </BirthDate>
                                <Name>
                                    <value>
                                        <given qualifier="IN">$3</given>
                                            <family>$4</family>
                                    </value>
                                </Name>
                            </parameterList>
                        </queryByParameter>
                    </controlActEvent>
                </TOTO>
                </ns2:QueryReqWS>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg xmlns:ns2="http://hiddenUrl.com/"
                    evaluator="xml"
                    expression="string(//ns2:testRequest/ns2:person/ns2:gender)"/>
               <arg xmlns:ns2="http://hiddenUrl.com/"
                    evaluator="xml"
                    expression="string(//ns2:testRequest/ns2:person/ns2:birthday)"/>
               <arg xmlns:ns2="http://hiddenUrl.com/"
                    evaluator="xml"
                    expression="string(//ns2:testRequest/ns2:person/ns2:lastname)"/>
               <arg xmlns:ns2="http://hiddenUrl.com/"
                    evaluator="xml"
                    expression="string(//ns2:testRequest/ns2:person/ns2:firstname)"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http:/test/testMessage/Unknown" format="soap11">
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

The sample message is the following:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Body>
    <ns2:testRequest xmlns:ns2="http://com.hiddenurl/">
    <ns2:person>
    <ns2:gender>M</ns2:gender>
    <ns2:lastname>Man</ns2:lastname>
    <ns2:firstname>Spider</ns2:firstname>
    <ns2:birthday>20150301</ns2:birthday>
    </ns2:person>
    </ns2:testRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Soap 1.1 Example message:

```
    <id root="1234"/>
     ...
    <controlActEvent classCode="CACT" moodCode="EVN">
       ...
        <queryByParameter>
            <queryId root="456"/>
            <responseModalityCode code="R"/>
            <parameterList>
                <BirthDate>
                    <value xsi:type="TS" specializationType="TS.FULLDATE" value="20150301"/>
                </BirthDate>
                <Gender>
                    <value code="M" >
                    </value>
                </Gender>    
                <Name>
                    <value>
                        <given qualifier="IN">Spider</given>
                            <family>Man</family>
                    </value>
                </Name>
            </parameterList>
        </queryByParameter>
    </controlActEvent>
</TOTO>
</ns2:QueryReqWS>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the ESB can not build the message properly. Please check whether your content type header is either text/xml or application/xml. Enable wirelog as follows.

Shotdown the ESB instance.
Locate the log4j.properties file resides under the $ESB_HOME/repository/conf directory and uncomment the following line

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
```

Then paste the ESB console logs here. You may see the ContentType header there.

Also the symbol '>>' gives the contents written into the ESB and '<<' gives the contents written out of the ESB.

Comment: Thanks, I will be able to debug the problem since if I use the soap passed to the end point in SOAP UI I got an exception. I will keep you informed about my progress.

Comment: I will accept this as an answer since you've allowed me to compare between a payload from SOAPUI and the WSO2 payload. I was missing an header that I added like: <property name="Authorization"
 value="1234" scope="transport"/>